# Show/hide + v-on:click for single page aplication vue.js

Tags: vue.js, show-hide

I try to call different elements(3 html pages like home, login and chat page) in spa with a v-show/v-if with von:click v-button.

Does somebody has a clear example?

Comment: Why don't you try to use router? If I were you, I wouldn't handle a page like an element. This is a router case. https://router.vuejs.org/

Comment: Thanks, but for this spa I have to merge all htmls into one and show/hide div onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      page: 'login'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loginClick() {
      this.page = 'home'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="page === 'login'">
    <button @click="loginClick">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div v-if="page === 'home'">
    home page
    <a href="" @click.prevent="page = 'chat'">go to chat</a>
  </div>
  <div v-if="page === 'chat'">
    chat page
  </div>
</div>
```